# Using the Text Object Interface to insert a row in a table

Tags: c, tom

I want to use the Text Object Model to insert a row in a table at the caret position in a rich text control using the C programming language (Pelles C).

I tried the following code:

```
    HRESULT hr;
    ITextRange2 *textRange2 = NULL;
    ITextRow *textRow = NULL;

    hr = TextDocument2->lpVtbl->Range2(TextDocument2, 0, 0, &textRange2);
    hr = textRange2->lpVtbl->GetRow(textRange2, &textRow);
    hr = textRow->lpVtbl->Insert(textRow, numbRows);
    hr = textRow->lpVtbl->Release(textRow);
    textRange2->lpVtbl->Release(textRange2);
```

However, this inserts a row at the top of the table instead of inserting a row above or below the row where the caret is located. I am convinced that the line:

`hr = TextDocument2->lpVtbl->Range2(TextDocument2, 0, 0, &textRange2);`

locates the row containing the caret as I have used this to delete a row containing the caret.

I am using the TOM.h file from https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/um/TOM.h

How should I amend the code to insert a row at the current caret position?

**** Update****

After hours of experimentation, I have come up with the following solution to insert a row in a table. The new row is inserted below the row containing the caret.

```
void TOM_tblInsertRow(long numbRows){

    ITextRange2 *textRange2 = NULL;
    ITextRow *textRow = NULL;
    long rowIndex = 0;

   TextDocument2->lpVtbl->Range2(TextDocument2, 0, 0, &textRange2);
    ITextSelection *textSelection = NULL;
    TextDocument2->lpVtbl->GetSelection(TextDocument2, &textSelection);
    textSelection->lpVtbl->GetIndex(textSelection, tomSelectionRow, &rowIndex);
    textSelection->lpVtbl->Release(textSelection);
    textRange2->lpVtbl->Move(textRange2, tomSelectionRow, rowIndex, &rowIndex);
    textRange2->lpVtbl->GetRow(textRange2, &textRow);
    textRow->lpVtbl->Insert(textRow, numbRows);

    textRow->lpVtbl->Release(textRow);
   textRange2->lpVtbl->Release(textRange2);
}
```

However, this will not insert a row if the caret is in the last  row of the table. How can I overcome this issue?